# move table from one schema to another schema ?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to move table from one schema to another schema in mysql , can anybody tell me how can I do this .

Comment: Are you talking about alter an existing table's schema, or moving the data from one table to another table with a different schema, or ?

Comment: thanks for reply , i wanna move table with all data in it from one schema to another schema

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If both schema is on same server then Alter table can be used to move tables from one db to another.

```
alter table old_db.fooTable rename new_db.fooTable
```

Comment: what worked for me was:`ALTER SCHEMA new_dbo 
    TRANSFER old_dbo.Test`

Comment: @powernit this is a `T-SQL` syntax for MSSQL, while @p27 asked about `MySQL`

Comment: alternate syntax: `rename old_db.fooTable to new_db.fooTable`

Answer (score 6):

Moving tables with space characters in between should be enclosed.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE `schema1`.`tbl somename` 
RENAME TO  `schema2`.`tbl somename` ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving fooTable from old_db_schema to new_db_schema will be a 2 step process:

Step 1:

```
CREATE SCHEMA new_db_schema --Assuming you do not have new schema
GO
```

Step 2:

```
ALTER SCHEMA new_db_schema
TRANSFER old_db_schema.fooTable 
GO
```

Comment: The question was about MySQL specifically. But the syntax in this answer isn't supported in MySQL (apparently it's for T-SQL instead).