# How to move table from one data base to another

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to move my existing hive tale from one database to another along with the data.

for example if i move my table from source.table_1 to dest.table_2

I shouldint see any data or table that associated with my source.table_1 in my source database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [move table from one schema to another schema ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910261/move-table-from-one-schema-to-another-schema)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`RENAME`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenameTable) the table.

```
ALTER TABLE source.table_1 RENAME TO dest.table_2;
```