# SQL Server : creating a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

When creating a table in SQL Server, it is created using `dbo.<tableName>` format.

I want to change **dbo**.tableName to **source**.tableName, as I want to import data into a source table and then cook that data.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910261/move-table-from-one-schema-to-another-schema

Comment: You are correct. I remove the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about schemas. If the schema   `source` doesn't exist yet, you need to run `create schema source`. Once the schema exists it's as easy as `create table source.tableName (...)`.